# Notifications/Mail com Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Estou com problemas para disparar notificações com Laravel 5.4, já segui os passos da documentação, porém não obtive sucesso.

Segue meu código

> \LaraShop\Users\Notifications\MessageUser

```
<?php namespace LaraShop\Users\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use LaraShop\Users\Emails\MailMessage as Mailable;

class MessageUser extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    private $message;
    private $user;
    public function __construct($message, $user)
    {
        //
        $this->message = $message;
        $this->user = $user;
    }
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        return (new Mailable($this->message))->to($this->message->user->email);
    }    
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return json_encode($this->message->toArray());
    }
}
```

Classe `MailMessage` para disparo do E-mail.

> \LaraShop\Users\Emails\MailMessage

```
<?php namespace LaraShop\Users\Emails;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use LaraShop\Users\Entities\Message;

class MailMessage extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;       
    private $message;   
    public function __construct(Message $message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.default', [
            'email' => [
                'title' => 'Hello World!',
                'text' => 'Hello World!',
                'button' => [
                    'label' => 'Acessar',
                    'url' => route('page.users.messages.index'),
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
}
```

onde eu chamo a `Facade` de `Notification` do `Laravel`.

```
public function show(Request $request)
{
    $message = Message::find($request->item);
    \Notification::send($message, new MessageUser($message, $message->user));
    return view('users::pages.messages.show', [
        'message' => $message,
        'user' => \Auth::user()
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema!?

Comment: Não envia o E-mail e também não salva no banco a notificação.

Comment: Do jeito que está era só pra enviar e-mail.

Answer (score 1):

Para que a notificação seja gravada no banco, no array de retorno do seu método `via` deve ter o item `database`.

Por exemplo:

```
/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param mixed $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
 public function via($notifiable)
 {
     return ['database', 'mail'];
 }
```

Você também precisa criar a tabela `notifications` com os comandos:

```
php artisan notifications:table

php artisan migrate
```

Fonte: [Documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/notifications#database-notifications)

Comment: Já havia criado a tabela, ainda continua sem mandar.